How to route message from Docker container to localhost
Problem Statement
I have two Docker containers: Sender and Receiver. My goal is to send a message from Sender to Receiver, and then forward this message to the localhost of my machine on a specific port.
Dockerfile for Sender:
FROM ubuntu

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional
COPY sender.sh /sender.sh
RUN chmod +x  /sender.sh
EXPOSE 8080
CMD ["/sender.sh"]

sender.sh
#!/bin/bash

echo "Received a connection at $(date)" | nc cont2 8080
echo "Message sent"

Dockefile for receiver:
FROM ubuntu:latest

RUN apt-get update && apt-get install -y netcat-traditional

COPY receiver.sh /receiver.sh

RUN chmod +x /receiver.sh

EXPOSE 8080
EXPOSE 12345
CMD ["/receiver.sh"]

receiver.sh:
#!/bin/sh

# Listen on port 8080 and forward the message to port 1234
nc -lkp 8080 | while read msg; do
    # Echo the received message
    echo "Received: $msg"

    # Forward the message to another port (1234)
    echo "$msg" | netcat localhost 12345
done

From what I understand, the localhost in receiver.sh refers to the localhost of the container, not my machine. I need help ensuring that the message sent from the Sender container is properly received by the Receiver container and then forwarded to the localhost of my machine on port 12345, where I can use some tool like curl to see the message.
Commands to build the containers:
docker run -d -p 12345:12345 --name cont2 cont2

docker run -d --link cont2:cont2 --name sender sender

